# Postfix 3 with UTF8 email addresses errors

Tags: linux, email, utf-8, postfix-mta

Even though we have built postfix 3 with UTF8 support, we get this error when sending a message to an email with a UTF8 character : "User unknown in local recipient table"

I believe the error is because the UTF8 email address no longer contains an @ symbol for postfix to parse and believes it's a local address/alias. From the logs :

reject: RCPT from unknown[10.10.10.10]: 550 5.1.1 <=?UTF-8?B?4piehY2suaXM= ?=>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table; from= to=<=?UTF-8?B?4piehY2suaXM =?=> proto=ESMTP helo=

Are we missing some configuration in postfix for it to parse the UTF8 address?

There's not a lot of current information regarding getting Postfix and UTF8 working. I understand that even if our server routes the email, others may not, but we'd like to do what we can to support these new email addresses.